# My button will not cancel after clicking "cancel" in my popup

Tags: javascript

I have a button that acts as a link. The onclick is the myAlert() function shown below. The function creates a popup asking if you want to continue. It still goes to the next page even if you hit "cancel". What should I do?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="grey" align="center">
<a href="333.html"><button onclick="myAlert()">Sign up</button></a><a href="22.html"><button >Log in</button></a> 

<script>
    function myAlert(){
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to sign up?')) {

  console.log('Thank you.');
} else {


}
    }
    </script>       
            
  
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please tell me if any part of this is hard to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You placed the button inside the link itself. Therefore after closing the dialog, the browser processes the onclick event of the link which results in browsing to the to the link target.

You can remove the link elements completely and handle everything using the buttons:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="grey" align="center">
<button onclick="myAlert('333.html')">Sign up</button><button onclick="window.location.href='22.html'">Log in</button> 

<script>
    function myAlert(redirect){
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to sign up?')) {
           window.location.href=redirect
  console.log('Thank you.');
} else {


}
    }
    </script>       
            
  
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `preventDefault()` method to cancel the default action that belongs to going to the next page.

```js
function myAlert(e) {
  
  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to sign up?')) {

    console.log('Thank you.');
  } else {
     e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>repl.it</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body bgcolor="grey" align="center">
  <a href="333.html"><button onclick="myAlert(event)">Sign up</button></a><a href="22.html"><button >Log in</button></a>


</body>

</html>
```